# Featherlight Gallery with AJAX-loaded HTML

Tags: featherlight.js

I created a gallery with AJAX loaded HTML instead of images. It works, except that only the first click on previous or next works. Subsequent clicks do not fire:

```
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
  <a href="casestudy_001.html" data-featherlight="ajax">Case Study #1</a>
  <a href="casestudy_002.html" data-featherlight="ajax">Case Study #2</a>
  <a href="casestudy_003.html" data-featherlight="ajax">Case Study #3</a>
</div>
```

I don't want to use an iframe in this case. Any ideas how to re-init the click event listener?

Comment: Mmm, it's a bug, sorry. I'll try to fix it today

Comment: Hi! Have you had a chance to fix this bug?